# Can't connect to MariaDB Database [JAVA]

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb

I'm working on a Twitch Chat Bot which should output messages when someone types a command. The commands are getting saved in a MariaDB Database called TB. The first problem I have is that I cant connect to the Database. I saw a lot of stackoverflow posts but none of them could help me. I've never connected a database to a java program before.

My database connect method:

```
 public void DBConnect(){

        try {

            String url = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/TB";
            String user = "root";
            String password = "";

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

            if (con != null) {
                System.out.println("Connected to the database test");
            }

        }catch(Exception ex){

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```

I'm executing the method whenever I run my program:

```
public TwitchBotFenster() throws IOException, Exception {

    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    initComponents();

    ReadServerMessages.start();

    DBConnect();

    }
```

The exception I get looks like this:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/TB
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at main.TwitchBotFenster.DBConnect(TwitchBotFenster.java:166)
at main.TwitchBotFenster.<init>(TwitchBotFenster.java:31)
at main.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

I have already downloaded the jdbc and imported it to my library. Apache and MySql are running on XAMPP.

Comment: That error means that the MariaDB JDBC Driver `.jar` file is *not* on the classpath at runtime.

Comment: @Andreas what should I do now? I did import the mariadb jdbc. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Have tried using `jdbc:mysql:` instead of `jdbc:mariadb:`

Comment: Yeah, your question also mentioned that you *"imported it to my library"*. Which jar file did you import and what tool (IDE) are you importing it into, but more importantly, *how* are you running the code?

Comment: Yes, still getting the same exception @YoungMillie

Comment: Do you have the `mariadb-java-client-1.5.5.jar` file in your library / classpath?

Comment: @W-S I had the mariadb-java-client-1.5.5-javadoc.jar in my lib. Fixed it now, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Maven it may be fastest to shade the jdbc into your JAR. Essentially what's happening right now is that you're able to code with it because you have the dependency listed, but when you actually run your bot you're not loading the dependency.